# Probability spread over number of days with finite wins

Tags: probability, games

I am trying to figure out how to get odds based on a few factors and running into a few problems since I am a developer that is terrible at statistics/probability. My problem seems to be much like how the McDonalds Monopoly game functions with a few other variables.

Here is what I am working with:

- 32 day contest
- 50 available cards
- 13 of 50 cards are "rare"
- Unknown number of entries
- 1,172 total prizes
- One entry each day draws 5 cards

My largest problem is to be sure that of the 32 days, not all the prizes are given out in the beginning nor end but evenly distributed based off of the odds of getting a single "rare" card.

Can anyone help with the math involved in figuring out what the odds should be for a single rare card based on number of prizes and days of the contest? Is there some other factor that I am missing as well? Do I need to estimate the number of people playing to figure out the probability?

Help, of course, is very much appreciated.